The size a subset A ⊂[N] be without non-trivial solution to x+y=2z with x, y , z ∈ A and x,y,z>=0 in terms of N
I was shown a proof of this recently which first started by iteratively listing numbers 0-30 and getting rid of numbers that stop the set from satisfying the above condition (for example 2 is removed as 0+2=2(1) and so is 5 as 3+5=2(4). The proof then stated that all numbers eliminated with this method had 2 as one of their digits in base 3(this confused me ). Then it stated that the size would be 2^(log_{3}N) which confused me even more and I do not understand how you would get there.
